# Loop through elements with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have the following working code on greasemonkey:

```
var qtt = 100;

var filler1 = document.getElementById("s1_0");
var filler2 = document.getElementById("s2_0");
var filler3 = document.getElementById("s3_0");
var filler4 = document.getElementById("s4_0");
var filler5 = document.getElementById("s5_0");
var filler6 = document.getElementById("s6_0");
var filler7 = document.getElementById("s7_0");

filler1.value = qtt;
filler2.value = qtt;
filler3.value = qtt;
filler4.value = qtt;
filler5.value = qtt;
filler6.value = qtt;
filler7.value = qtt;
```

Where the "sN_0" are the names of inputs, the code works, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do the same, to loop through all the id names or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple loop doing that your code does

```
var qtt=100;   
for (var i =1;i<8;i++){
    document.getElementById("s"+i+"_0").value=qtt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [jQuery](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries#jQuery), try the following.

```
var qtt = 100;
$('[id]').each(function() {
    if(/^s\d_0$/.test(this.id)) {
        this.value = qtt;
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MK7QG/)